# Yum - DHCP package conflict

Tags: yum, dhcp

Get this error in Yum:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/man/man5/dhcp-eval.5.gz from install of dhcp-common-12:4.1.1-53.P1.0.1.el6_9.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package dhclient-12:4.1.1-12.P1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/dhcp-options.5.gz from install of dhcp-common-12:4.1.1-53.P1.0.1.el6_9.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package dhclient-12:4.1.1-12.P1.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a package conflict, can you try this:

```
yum -y upgrade dhclient
```

And then run:

```
yum -y install dhcp
```